# Contributions with Frozen Financial Type Field

Tags: wordpress, contributions

I'm finding that some contributions do not allow financial types to be changed. Normally there is a dropdown that allows a user to select a different financial type, but sometimes the field is frozen (see screenshot). Can someone explain this, or provide a solution?

[image: Un-editable Financial Type]

Answer (score 1):

Are they related to membership or event fees? Maybe coming from here:

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.15.1/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution.php#L825

Comment: That does appear to be what is causing it, but why is it being done. What is the purpose for not allowing financial types to be changed?